# Can't import version (in setup.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, version, setuptools, setup.py

There is some problem with importing version module, which I can't figure it out.
Tree of my project:

```
├── install.sh
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── tankduels.py
    ├── Tanks.txt
    └── version.py
```

setup.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from setuptools import setup
from src.version import __version__

setup(
    name='tankduels',
    version=__version__,
    description='Console game',
    # long_description='Player choose his and enemy tank. ',
    # packages=['src'],
    # install_requires=[],
    package_dir={'':'src'},
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["tankduels = tankduels:main"]},
)
```

version.py:

```
__version__="1.0"
```

If I execute this command: `python3 setup.py bdist_rpm` (I am on Fedora). I got following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/commrat/projects/tank-duels/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILD/tankduels-1.0/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from src.version import __version__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.version'
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.joaIdn (%build
```

What am I doing wrong? I really don't get it, because if I execute this: `python3 setup.py --version` It will show good output:

```
1.0
```

Comment: refer to this topic https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/

Comment: It's because of `package_dir={'': 'src'}`.